# Android Studio updating View- moving game object

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm working on a maze game in android studio. I want to create enemy (rectangle for now) which will move randomly in a maze, but I can't update a view. I tried creating a TimerTask, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

onDraw method

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
    enemy = cells[(COLS - 1) / 2][(ROWS - 1) / 2];
    canvas.drawRect(
        enemy.col * cellSize + margin,
        enemy.row * cellSize + margin,
        (enemy.col + 1) * cellSize - margin,
        (enemy.row + 1) * cellSize - margin,
        enemyPaint);
}

    updateEnemyTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            moveEnemy();
        }
    };
```

```
public void updateEnemy() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateEnemyTask, startTime, offsetTime);

}
```

```
private void moveEnemy () {

    Direction direction;
    random = new Random();
    int randomDirection = random.nextInt(Direction.values().length);
    direction = Direction.values()[randomDirection];

    switch (direction) {
        case UP:
            if (!enemy.topWall)
                enemy = cells[enemy.col][enemy.row - 1];
                break;
        case DOWN:
            if (!enemy.bottomWall)
               enemy = cells[enemy.col][enemy.row + 1];
               break;
        case LEFT:
            if (!enemy.leftWall)
               enemy = cells[enemy.col - 1][enemy.row];
               break;
        case RIGHT:
            if (!enemy.rightWall)
               enemy = cells[enemy.col + 1][enemy.row];
               break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update your view you must call the `invalidate()` method

**Warning**:
Add a thread in the constructor of the view, to update your view:

```
new Thread(() -> {
   while (true){
      try{

         //Sleep 100 millis
         sleep(100);

         invalidate();
   
      }catch(Throwable ex){
         //Handle the exception here
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}.start());
```

But why aren't you using a game framework?